# Drupal 7 site loads very slow

Tags: drupal-7

We have a simple CMS site in drupal 7. The site was loading fine. From the last couple of weeks site loads very slow. It takes more than 10 mins to load front end and admin side pages. We cleared cache and increased memory_limit, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you changed something that could cause that issue? Have you contact your host?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything. Also contacted host, they said its drupal issue. We noticed that there was a message on admin side like 'Download and import interface translations'.But that message not showing now. Is this something related with the slow issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, sounds to me like it's database related. 
See if this link helps:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1131048#comment-6546898